# Issue with Sending Stream after Reconnecting to Ant Media Server Android SDK

Tags: android, kotlin, webrtc, ant-media-server-sdk

We are encountering a challenge related to the Ant Media Server Android SDK while dealing with stream reconnection scenarios. I would like to provide you with a detailed overview of the issue we are facing.

We have two devices, Device A (using the Android SDK) and Device B (also using the Android SDK), participating in a room where they exchange audio and video streams. In our use case, if Device A experiences a loss of connectivity and is subsequently turned off, it disconnects from the room. However, the room remains active with Device B still present.

When Device A is powered back on and reconnects to the same room, it successfully receives streams from Device B. However, we've noticed that Device A is unable to send its own stream.

We are using the Ant Media Server Android SDK for Device A and the Android SDK for Device B.

To address this issue, we are seeking your insights into the following:

How does the Android SDK notify the client application about the reconnection state?
Once the reconnection is established, how does the SDK inform the client application about it?
Which delegate of the AntMediaClient/WebRTCClient should we rely on to manage the display of the "Reconnection..." status and the actions related to replaying/republishing streams?

We tried call back of the stream. Which we are unsuccessful. Is there anyone who can help me out